# Чем выделяется?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

У вас же эта()как её()гражданская позиция.

Выделяется запятыми или тире?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просторечные добавочные замечания - всё равно замечания, не относящиеся к смыслу предложения, выражают заминку в речи, иногда растерянность,значит, тоже выполняют функцию вводного сочетания, запятыми обосабливаются, хотя в речи их быть не должно, однако для передачи речи героев используются в худ. произведениях.Тире выделяют вставные конструкции с самостоятельным смыслом, здесь смысла нет, только возглас, близкий к междометию -запятые.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь уместны многоточия: ***У вас же эта...как её...гражданская позиция.*** 
Вариант: ***У вас же эта,как её...гражданская позиция.***

Помните:
 "***...она жила с другим человеком... и я там, тогда...с этой, как её...

-С кем? - спросил Бездомный.

-С этой...ну...с этой...ну...-ответил гость и защёлкал пальцами.

-Вы были женаты?

-– Ну да, вот же я и щелкаю… на этой… Вареньке, Манечке… нет, Вареньке… еще платье полосатое… музей… впрочем, я не помню.***"

Comment: Согласна, я ответила на вопрос"запятыми или тире",другие варианты просто не рассматривала

Comment: Да, я Вас понимаю.

Comment: Спасибо большое.